# How to calculate the time difference based on multiple conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like as shown here. I am trying to calculate the persons unavailable time based on their status

**Case 1**: if the `start_date` and `end_date` are the same and `status='UNKNOWN'` and `workstatus='ERROR'`, then I have to consider the `end_date` to next same status like unknown and error (rowid 3 and 8). I have to calculate the time difference between `end_date` of first record and `start_date` of next record (which are highlighted in blue color "2023-04-24 10:15:24" to "2023-04-24 10:21:24"). If person is unavailable for multiple times in a day then this operation should be done for next unknown i.e rowid 14,15 "2024-04-24 12:45:29" to "2023-04-24 13:45:29".

**Case 2**: if there is no further record with status of UNKNOWN and ERROR (for that day), Then we have to consider the previous record (Idle or Active any record which is not unknown for that day, in this case of person 1 rowid 11) i.e for record 13, record 11 enddate is start time. time difference between "2023-04-24 15:12:09" to "2023-04-24 15:47:00" (highlighted in yellow color)

[image]

In the end, the expected result would be like:

[image]

Here is the script I use:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.human_sample 
(
    rowid int, 
    person_id int, 
    start_date datetime, 
    end_date datetime, 
    status varchar(100), 
    work_status varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (1, 1,  '2023-04-24 10:10:15',  '2023-04-24 10:15:24',  'IDLE', 'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (2, 1,  '2023-04-24 10:15:24'   ,'2023-04-24 10:19:45', 'IDLE', 'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (3, 2,  '2023-04-24 10:15:24',  '2023-04-24 10:15:24',  'UNKNOWN',  'ERROR')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (4, 1,  '2023-04-24 10:45:45',  '2023-04-24 11:35:21',  'IDLE', 'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (5, 1,  '2023-04-24 11:35:21',  '2023-04-24 11:35:21',  'IDLE', 'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (6, 1,  '2023-04-24 11:35:21',  '2023-04-24 11:55:41',  'IDLE', 'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (7, 1,  '2023-04-24 11:55:41',  '2023-04-24 13:25:11',  'ACTIVE',   'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (8, 2,  '2023-04-24 10:21:24',  '2023-04-24 10:21:24',  'UNKNOWN',  'ERROR')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (9, 2,  '2023-04-24 10:21:24',  '2023-04-24 11:45:49',  'IDLE', 'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (10,    1,  '2023-04-24 13:25:11',  '2023-04-24 14:12:41',  'ACTIVE',   'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (11,    1,  '2023-04-24 14:12:41',  '2023-04-24 15:12:09',  'IDLE', 'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (12,    2,  '2023-04-24 11:45:49',  '2023-04-24 12:45:29',  'IDLE', 'OK')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (13,    1,  '2023-04-24 15:47:00',  '2023-04-24 15:47:00',  'UNKNOWN',  'ERROR')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (14,    2,  '2023-04-24 12:45:29',  '2023-04-24 12:45:29',  'UNKNOWN',  'ERROR')
INSERT INTO dbo.human_sample VALUES (15,    2,  '2023-04-24 13:45:29',  '2023-04-24 13:45:29',  'UNKNOWN',  'ERROR')
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I think you have too many (or too much?) gaps in your data to calculate the  unavailable time based on their status (and produce a reliable output).

Answer (score 0):

the condition going from IDLE to UNKNOWN was not able to be solved because it requires specifying which IDLE time (or the timestamp after ACTIVE) which is a different condition but this gives you the partial solution for time difference for the UNKNOWN/ERROR codes

```
select *, time(start_date - lag(end_date,1)
over(partition by person_id order by rowid))
as time_unavailable from (select * from human_sample
where status = 'UNKNOWN' and work_status = 'ERROR') as test;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Yo3nCqRboawS5EyjnTwU1/0) here

Answer (score 0):

To handle your two different cases, you can do it in separate query and then use `UNION ALL` to combine the result as one.

Firstly, count the number of `UNKNOWN` status, when there is more than 2, it is `case 1` else `case 2`. Refer to `case_flag`

For `case 1`, you only interested in those lines with `UNKNOWN` status. Use `row_number()` to generate a running number which will allow you to group 2 row as one. Then just find the `datediff()` with `min( date )` and `max ( date )`

For `case 2`, use `lag()` to get previous row `end_datetime` and then calcualte the `datediff()`

```
with
cte as
(
  select rowid, person_id, start_date, end_date, status, work_status, 
         [date] = convert(date, start_date), 
         case_flag = case when sum (case when status = 'UNKNOWN' then 1 else 0 end) 
                               over (partition by person_id, convert(date, start_date))
                               > 1
                          then 1
                          else 2
                          end
  from   human_sample
),
-- case 1 logic
case_1_cte as
(
  select person_id, [date],
         rn = row_number() over (partition by person_id, [date] order by start_date),
         start_date, end_date
  from   cte
  where  case_flag = 1
  and    status = 'UNKNOWN'
),
case_1 as
(  
  select person_id, [date], 
         Unavailable_time_in_seconds = datediff(second, min(end_date), max(start_date))
  from   case_1_cte
  group by person_id, [date], (rn - 1) / 2 
),
-- case 2 logic
case_2_cte as
(
   select person_id, [date], start_date, end_date, status,
          prev_end_date = lag(end_date) over (partition by person_id, [date]
                                  order by start_date)
   from   cte
   where  case_flag = 2
),
case_2 as
(
  select person_id, [date], 
         Unavailable_time_in_seconds = datediff(second, prev_end_date, start_date)
  from   case_2_cte
  where  status = 'UNKNOWN'
)
-- final result
select person_id, [date], Unavailable_time_in_seconds
from   case_1
union all
select person_id, [date], Unavailable_time_in_seconds
from   case_2
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/yCdYRh6N)